# Running/Online Outlier Detection?

Tags: outliers, anomaly-detection, online-algorithms

I get a stream of values online from a potentially non-stationary distribution, and would like to calculate whether a value is "rare" i.e. higher values only occur once in every 100 or 1000 values. It appears I also can not make assumptions about the distribution of these values - but often they seem to belong to families with long right tails.

Can anyone recommend any techniques on how to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "rare", precisely? If you mean nothing more than that they are the highest 1% or 0.1%, you could use sample quantiles to identify them (i.e. take the highest 1% of the sample). Without some assumptions, you can't do much more.

Comment: One dimensional, or multidimensional? How about using histograms?